# grab one random item from flat text file - php?

Tags: php, random

I basically just want to pull out one random testimonial from a flat text file that I have. I have the code to pull them in, shuffle them, and display them ALL using a foreach statement.... but I am not sure what to do if I want just ONE. Should I change up the foreeach?

```
srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
$f_contents = file_get_contents("testimonials.txt");
$line = explode("\n",$f_contents);
$noe = count($line); 
shuffle($line);
foreach ($line as $str ){
//echo code to output 
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

once shuffled just use the first one in the array

```
echo $line[0];
```

array_rand() and not shuffling is probably faster

```
echo $line[array_rand($line)];
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!  It's always the simple things I don't think of! :)

Comment: when i see data like this in a file, i always think it would probably be better of stored in a RDBMS